# Using a custom object instead of @FormParam as JAX-RS resource input

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I'm having an example code:

```
@PUT
public String method(@FormParam("firstName") String firstName, 
                     @FormParam("lastName") String lastName ) {
    Person person = new Person(firstName, lastName);
    // ...
}
```

I would like to stop using @FormParams and use Person instead:

```
@PUT
public String method(@Person person) {
    // ...
}
```

What would be the best way to do it?

I'm experimenting with a custom BodyReader but than I have to "manually" parse the InputStream in `readFrom` method.

Is that the right way to do it and if yes what is the best way to transform the InputStream into KEY => VALUE HashMap?

Comment: The question is if you would be expecting to receive a POJO without changing your current way of invoking the http method using form parameters or if you intend to receive a POJO and pass it explicitly in your http request body. For the second you don't need anything. You just need the appropriate content handler in your app.

Comment: I would like to keep the generic way of passing POST/GET params (&key=val)

Comment: there is an @BeanParam option, see: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1905

Comment: Could you promote your comment to an answer. I would like to accept it.

Comment: glad it worked for you, Lukasz, I added it as an answer now..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is an @BeanParam option, see:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1905

Comment: Is it a valid design to have a model which will be in the same time JavaBean? or perhaps I should have separate Bean classes and initialise models out of them?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Probably you transport only a single entity instance within that method, in which case you could simply avoid annotating the `person` parameter with any JAX-RS annotations. In the JAX-RS specification this is called an entity parameter and there must be a single such parameter in a REST method, and then it is automatically decoded by an registered entity providers.
2. Change your `Person` class so that its constructor receives a single String as a parameter, and to the decoding in the constructor. Extracted from [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1905):

> In general the Java type of the method parameter may:
>
> - Be a primitive type;   -Have a constructor that accepts a single
>     String argument;
> - Have a static method named valueOf or fromString that accepts a single String argument (see, for example, Integer.valueOf(String) and
>     java.util.UUID.fromString(String));
> - Have a registered implementation of javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverterProvider JAX-RS extension SPI that
>     returns a javax.ws.rs.ext.ParamConverter instance capable of a "from
>     string" conversion for the type. or
> - Be List, Set or SortedSet, where T satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting collection is read-only.